# How to get dataset label in a data step?

Tags: sas, attr

I wanna get the label of dataset which is in the `set` statement but I haven't find a beautiful method.

I have tried this:

```
data test;
    set sashelp.class;
    rc = open("sashelp.class");
    label = attrc(rc,"label");
    rc = close(rc);
run;
```

It works but also have a weak point that I have to write the name of dataset in `open()` function.
I am looking for a better way to replace writing it manually since I have dozens of similar steps.

I have tried `&syslast` too, but it doesn't work. May there is some way else?

Comment: Oh, one thing forgot. Only one single dataset in the `set` statement.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this, but someone might surprise me. If there is a way to determine the name of currently-open data sets, it would have to handle lots of edge cases related to multiple data sets on a set statement, multiple set statements, conditional set statements, etc. I would just do '%let ds = sashelp.class;' before your step and then replace both instances with '&ds'.

Comment: And of course, you can also just fetch the label from the DICTIONARY.TABLES view in a separate step, if that's cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe INDSNAME

```
18   data _null_;
19      set sashelp.class(obs=2 drop=_all_) sashelp.shoes(obs=2 drop=_all_)indsname=indsname;
20      retain label;
21      if indsname ne lag(indsname) then do;
22         rc = open(indsname); label=attrc(rc,"label"); rc=close(rc);
23         end;
24      put _all_;
25
26      run;

indsname=SASHELP.CLASS label=Student Data rc=0 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
indsname=SASHELP.CLASS label=Student Data rc=. _ERROR_=0 _N_=2
indsname=SASHELP.SHOES label=Fictitious Shoe Company Data rc=0 _ERROR_=0 _N_=3
indsname=SASHELP.SHOES label=Fictitious Shoe Company Data rc=. _ERROR_=0 _N_=4
```

Answer (score 2):

Would statement style macros allowed by `IMPLMAC` qualify for a SAS beauty pageant ?

Repurpose the `SET` statement as a statement style macro that emits source code containing a normal `SET` statement and a data step variable assignment of the data set label retrieved via `ATTRC`.

Example:

```
%macro SET(data) / STMT;
  options IMPLMAC = 0; %* turn off implmac so following SET is normal token;
  SET &data;
  options IMPLMAC = 1; %* turn on implac so subsequent SET invoke this macro;
  %local id;
  %let id = %sysfunc(open(&data));
  %if (&id) %then %do;
    DSLABEL = %sysfunc(quote(%sysfunc(ATTRC(&ID,LABEL))));
    %let id = %sysfunc(close(&id));
  %end;
%mend;

data have(label="This is the data set I ""have""");
  x=1;
run;


options IMPLMAC=1 MPRINT;

data _null_;
  SET HAVE;
run;

options IMPLMAC=0;
```

Comment: Never see this before.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the advantage of statement style macros compared to name style macros?

Comment: From my viewpoint there is none.  Certainly there to maintain back compatibility.  Perhaps in the fog of earliest SAS the feature was developed to emulate or extend 'grammar' of procedures.  The statement style macro concept has similarities to command style macros (`CMDMAC`)

Comment: You are really knowledgeable, Richard.